# Thread safety of class data access

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have the following class for storing color values:

```
TMyColors = class
private
  Colors: array [0 .. MaxCols - 1, 0 .. MaxRows - 1] of TColor;
public
  NumColumns: Cardinal;
  NumRows: Cardinal;
  function GetColor1(col, row: Integer): TColor;
  function GetColor2(col, row: Integer): TColor;
end;

function TMyColors.GetColor1(col, row: Integer): TColor;
begin
  Result := Colors[col, row];
end;

function TMyColors.GetColor2(col, row: Integer): TColor;
begin
  if InRange(col, 0, NumColumns - 1) and InRange(row, 0, NumRows - 1) then
    Result := Colors[col, row]
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

NumColumns and NumRows indicate the numbers of actually used columns and rows.

This class should be used as global variable in a multi-threaded application, i.e., something like

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
     ...
     function GetColor1(col, row: Integer): TColor;
     function GetColor2(col, row: Integer): TColor;
     ...
  end;   

var
  MyColors: TMyColors;
  MyThread1, MyThread2, MyThread3: TMyThread;


function TMyThread.GetColor1(col, row: Integer): TColor;
begin
  Result := MyColors.GetColor1(col, row);
  { Alternative:
  if InRange(col, 0, MyColors.NumColumns - 1) and InRange(row, 0, MyColors.NumRows - 1) then
    Result := MyColors.GetColor1(col, row)
  else
    Result := 0;
  }
end;

function TMyThread.GetColor2(col, row: Integer): TColor;
begin
  Result := MyColors.GetColor2(col, row);
end;
```

I.e., all threads access the values in the global variable MyColors. I assume, that in this case the use of GetColor1 is thread safe, i.e., it can be used as indicated simultaneously in multiple threads
(provided, of course, that no other thread modifies the content of Colors). I also assume, that GetColor2 is not thread safe.

I am still unsure when something is thread safe and when not, so can somebody confirm that the above assumptions are true?

Comment: If you are just reading the data from `MyColors` while threads are running, then both `GetColor1` and `GetColor2` are thread-safe. However if you are modifying any of the data stored in `MyColors` instance then thread-safety depends on which parts of the data you are changing and you didn't show that code in your question, so it is impossible to give definite answer. `NumColums` and `NumRows` as unprotected publicly accessible data are the first potential source of unsafety.

Comment: I am aware that modifying the data is not thread-safe. That is done single-threaded. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The confusing part in your question is assumption that `GetColor2` is not thread-safe and you have said that you are reading the data. If you are just reading then this method is also thread-safe. So why do you think `GetColor2` is not thread-safe?

Comment: Do you know e.g. critical sections, semaphores and mutexes to make code parts thread safe?

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar Do I understand your comment correctly, that the use of calling parameters and local variables of a function or procedure is always thread safe (every thread has its own call stack?)? And calling functions like `InRange` is also thread safe (as long as these functions do not modify global variables)?

Comment: @Delphi Coder Yes, I know critical sections etc. But this was not the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition code is thread-safe if it manipulates the data in such manner that multiple threads using that data behave properly according to the code specifications and don't cause any unintended interactions.

If all threads (including the main thread) that can simultaneously access some data only read that data, then there cannot be any unintended interactions between threads as the data does not change while it is being read. Concurrency issues occur when at least one of the threads also modifies the data while others are reading it, and data retrieved can be in inconsistent state.

Because of the above, thread safety of some code and data it uses depends on the context and how it is used.

For your example, your data consists of several parts: `MyColors` global variable, and data within `TMyColors` instance referenced by `MyColors` variable - `Colors`, `NumColumns`, `NumRows`.

Again, if all threads only read any of the above data, either directly or through `GetColor1` and `GetColor2` methods that also only read the data, then such code is thread-safe.

When it comes to writing, situation is more complicated and depends on which data you are modifying:

- if any thread writes to `MyColors` global variable: assigning the new instance with `MyColors :=` , then nothing is thread safe
- if `Colors` array is being written to, it is not thread-safe
- if `NumColumns` or `NumRows` is being written to, then `GetColor2` is not thread-safe as it uses those fields, but `GetColors1` that only uses `Colors` field would be thread-safe even in such situation

Using local variables in a method is thread-safe as those are allocated locally every time you call a method and other threads don't have impact on them.

Accessing parameters within the method is thread-safe, but thread-safety of parameters is a bit more complicated matter as thread-safety depends on their type (thread safety of reference types also depends on whether other threads can access the same data that reference points to) and whether they are thread safe in broader context in the code that passes them to the method. In other words if you pass variable to a method and that variable can be written at that time by another thread, then such code is not thread-safe.